# How to pass digraph output to a JavaScript variable inside HTML code

Tags: javascript, html, graphviz

This is my dot.source output.
I assigned `index= dot.source`:

```
index= dot.source

digraph {
    edge [arrowhead=none]
    0 [label=cal360 id=cal360]
    1 [label=or120 id=or120]
    2 [label=ol372 id=ol372]
    3 [label=cal361 id=cal361]
    4 [label=sq513 id=sq513]
    5 [label=ld360 id=ld360]
    6 [label=al300 id=al300]
    7 [label=lf267 id=lf267]
    8 [label=nv479 id=nv479]
    9 [label=yr402 id=yr402]
    10 [label=gd326 id=gd326]
}



<script>
var dotSrc = {{ index }};

var graphviz = d3.select('#graph').graphviz();

function render(dotSrc) {
console.log('DOT source =', dotSrc);
var dotSrcLines = dotSrc.split('\n');
```

I want to pass it to `dotSrc` in my JavaScript which in in a different file.

Comment: edited for readability

Comment: Try to make your code somewhat functional and not have syntax errors to make it easier to determine your full intent here.

Comment: Is `digraph` supposed to be a JavaScript object? Are the double curly braces in `{{ index }}` indicative of React, some other library etc?